# GPP: Scheduled Task

Tags: group-policy

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am a beginner System Administrator trying to setup a scheduled task on GPO.  Ultimately, I am trying to execute a .exe to install an application at a scheduled time.  But first off, I tried testing my scheduled task with the display message function.  Please see down below for the steps I took:

- Created an OU
- Placed my computer into the OU
- Opened up the Group Policy Management Console
- Right clicked that OU -> Create a GPO and link it here
- Under Security Filtering added Authenticated Users and Domain Computers
- Linked and enforced the GPO
- Right Click GPO -> Edit
- Computer Configuration -> Preferences -> Control Panel Settings -> Scheduled Tasks
- Right Click Scheduled Tasks -> New Task (Scheduled Task Windows Vista and Later)
- Action: Update, Run only when user is logged on, Run with Highest Prvileges, Configure for Windows 7
- I set the schedule time and action to display a message
- I also enabled loopback processing on the Computer Configuration

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Nice explanation of what you did to set it up, but need more info about your results. What worked, what didn't? Have you checked gpresult or looked in the task scheduler?

Answer (score -2):

You can deploy software using Group Policy Software Installation GPSI for simpler and more flexibility :]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pp-ayBzR6u8

Comment: Please summarize the article that you linked, quoting any relevant code segments or configuration blocks.  Sites can change in the future or fail to load for any number of reasons.